# Is there a way that Excel can dynamically detect range when using SUMIF

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have this formula:

```
=SUMIF(E3:E18, TRUE, D3:D18)-M12
```

However the amount of data that I need to analyse changes each month, I need a way for the range to update automatically based on another cell, let's say k5.

Is there a way to modify this formula so that if k5 = 10 then it would sumif e3:e13, or if k5 = 20 ir would sumif e3:e23?

I'm tearing my hair out.

Comment: Might be an easier way. Can you share some sample data or a sample screenshot?

Comment: If you meant with 10 or 20 that this is the last used row for that month than yes, you can get a dynamic range using Index. And you won't even need K5 for it either.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=SUMIF($E$3:INDEX($E$3:$E$1000,$K$5,0),TRUE,$D$3:INDEX($D$3:$D$1000,$K$5,0))-M12
```

**EDIT**

Note:

- When there is a `10` in `K5`:

  - The above formula will `SUM` **ten (10)** rows which would be `D3:D12`.
  - If you want to `SUM` **eleven (11)** rows (`D3:D13`),

    - then change `$K$5` in the formula to `$K$5 + 1`